# Property 'set' does not exist on type Set

Tags: typescript

I got the following error: `TS2339: Property 'set' does not exist on type Set<>`
I have the following code:

```
const id = 123;
const a: Map<string, Set<File>> = new Map();
if (a.has(id)) {
    a.set(id, new Set());
    a.get(id).set(value);
}
```

Comment: What is `assetsQueue`? Is that the "set" you are referring to?

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't really make sense the way you've posted it. What is the distinction between `a` and `assetsQueue`?

Besides that, Set does not expose a method called `set`. You should be using `add`.

```
const id = '123';
const map: Map<string, Set<string>> = new Map();
map.set(id, new Set());
map.get(id).add('test');
```

Comment: Like I said, there is no `set` method on Set. You must use the `add` method as in my example